# Is there a function for applying a date-diff to a cronexpression?

Tags: cron

Suppose that I have a cron job which:

1. other admins might alter the cronexpression in the future, and
2. I want to notify users some fixed time (1 day, 2 hours, etc) in advance of every run of the job. It seems possible to construct a function (the particular language is not important to me) which inputs a valid cronexpression and a time difference ("+1d", "-12h", etc) and outputs a cronexpression which has been translated by some time delta (in the same way that many languages have a dateadd() for *fixed, individual* dates).

Examples:

```
 - cronshift("0 2 12 * *", "-3h") => "0 23 11 * *" # 2am on the 12th
   becomes 11pm on the 11th
 - cronshift("0 1 * * 0,4", "-24h) => "0 1 * *
   3,6" # 1am on Sun,Wed becomes 1am on Tues/Sat
 - cronshift("0 1-3 12 *
   *", "-2h") => ["0 23 11 * *", "0 0-1 12 * *"] # Extra credit: 1-3am on the 12th must be split across the 11th and 12th
```

Of course, there are a lot of complications (textual day-of-week names, '/' step values, etc) which I don't really need. Also, parsing the crontab to find/update the notification task is outside of the scope of this question. I also realize that another solution is to just calculate the date of the *next* cronexpression match, adjust that single date, and then make an at job to do the notification and create a new at job, but I'm intrigued by the complexity of time-shifting a cronexpression. **Is there a module in any semi-popular scripting language that already does something like this?**

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for a commercial grade scheduler with monitoring and logging with GUI and Web UI. Like this [one](https://cronitor.io/cron-job-monitoring).

I remember long ago there was a `GUI` utility for for `cron` and `at`. Named `gnome-schedule` hope it still exist.

You might also looking into higher-end task schedulers like `Puppet` and `Jenkins`

For high end scheduling with dynamic time calculations suggesting to use `systemd` timers.